# Android AlarmManager

Tags: android

This is my code:

```
public class Alarm extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (10 * 1000), pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

and

```
public final class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm worked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

By the above code i am able to get the `Toast`. Instead of `Toast` I want the `Dialog` to be appear after the alarm is set. Also I want to play the sound.

Any one help me please?

Comment: I fixed your code formatting for you so it displays correctly, but I suggest you work on your question a bit more. We like having code posted to look at (so that's a thumbs up! =) ), but it's also good if your question is a bit more indepth than what you've written here - re-writing a bit may help with getting answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot display a `Dialog` from a `BroadcastReceiver` or `Service`. You will be better served using an `Activity` (perhaps one using `Theme.Dialog`) and calling `startActivity()`.

Bear in mind, though, that users tend to really dislike it when background stuff pops up activities unannounced. For some apps -- alarm clocks, VOIP clients, etc. -- the user may be OK with it.

Comment: CommonsWare, startActivity() is showing error in broadcatReceiver.

Answer (score 1):

There is a cool trick to do that.

Here are the steps to do it:

- Place the `BroadcastReceiver` inside your `Activity` as an inner class.
- Instead of adding the `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest, you register yourself in the `onStart()` method of your `Activity`.
- You unregister in the `onPause()` method of your `Activity`.
- Inside the `BroadcastReceiver` you can call an `Activity`'s method that do exactly what you ask for.

Comment: That only works if the activity is going to be around. Typically, with `AlarmManager`, the point is for the activity to *not* be around.